# gson parsing error when found same keys with different types of value in json

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, gson

Getting large JSON response from API (generated by Jackson), and the object has its value only at its first occurrence in response. Second time when same object(with the same key) arrives it is replaced by some number/id.

JSON response looks like

```
[{id:1,Person:{name:"xyz",age:30}},
{id:2,Person:1}]
```

Now I want to store whole response in a list by following GSON code

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MainModel>>() {}.getType();
yourMainList = new Gson().fromJson(myres, listType);
//here myres is whole response and MainModel is my pojo class mapped with JSON response keys
```

but it gives me following error when duplicate key with id/number arrives second time in response.

> IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 11935 path $[1]. at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject

Is there any way to parse such JSON via GSON in android?

Comment: What do you expect to get from Person id 2, what should be the values of name and age, or would you prefer to just ignore it?

Comment: you can not do that, GSON works with objects, so you have to duplicate your object in your json instead of putting a reference

Comment: @Ahmed.ess in Android you are only limited by your imagination!

Comment: @IlyaGazman yes but in GSON, your are limited with GSON :D

Comment: @IlyaGazman I expect the original object which I got first time (e.g {name:"xyz",age:30}) So finally I expect whole object every time where I find just id (e.g. Person:1)

Comment: Can you show your `MainModel` & `Person`? What would you like to do with `Person:1` with those DTOs? Just ignore it?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use custom `JsonDeserializer` for problematic field, it could be like:

```
public class PersonDeSerializer implements JsonDeserializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public Person deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, 
                JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        try {
            return context.deserialize(json, typeOfT);
        } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
            // return null to elave null or make whatever kind of a person
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can set the problematic field deserialized with that adapter, like:

```
public class MainModel {
    private Long id;

    @JsonAdapter(PersonDeSerializer.class)
    private Person Person;  // should be person, but is Person in JSON
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide how do you handle the different variants of the Person class. Here is the simplest way to do it using [com.google.gson.JsonParser](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html).

```
private void start() {
    String json = "[{id:1,Person:{name:\"xyz\",age:30}},\n" +
            "{id:2,Person:1}]";

    HashMap<Integer, Person> map = new HashMap<>();

    JsonArray items = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
    items.forEach(jsonElement -> {
        JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        int id = jsonObject.get("id").getAsInt();
        JsonElement element = jsonObject.get("Person");
        if(element.isJsonObject()){
            JsonObject personObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            Person person = new Person();
            person.name = personObject.get("name").getAsString();
            person.age = personObject.get("age").getAsInt();
            map.put(id, person);
        }
        else {
            int personValue = element.getAsInt();
            map.put(id, new Person(personValue));
        }
    });

    for (int id : map.keySet()) {
        Person person = map.get(id);
        Log.d("myTag", id + ", name: " + person.name + ", age: " + person.age);
    }
}

class Person{
    String name;
    int age;

    Person(){}

    Person(int personValue) {
        // decide how the object should look
    }
}
```

Outputs:

> 1, name: xyz, age: 30
>   2, name: null, age: 0

If you like to work in a more generic way without hard typing your fields names you can use [Gson Custom Deserialization](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics)